# How to make $el.text() into number type?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I got this code in cypress to get only numbers in the table.

```
cy.get('.MuiTable-root > .MuiTableBody-root > .MuiTableRow-root  > .MuiTableCell-root:first-child')
   .each(($el, $index) => {
       if ($el.text() !== 'REDHAIR')
          values.push($el.text())
          expect(values.parseInt()).to.be.within(1,3)
```

But there is an error it said that parseInt() has no property in values.

cy.log has this result

```
log 1
log 2
log 3
```

Thanks.

Comment: values.map(value => parseInt(value)) [MDM](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/parseInt)

Comment: if ($el.text() !== REDHAIR')
                    values.push($el.text())
                    items = values.map(value => parseInt(value))
                    cy.log('Items', items)
                    expect(items).to.be.within(1,3) -> error expected  to be a number or a date

Answer (score 0):

I should be I am pretty sure

```
parseInt(values)
```

Comment: Not working.
if ($el.text() !== REDHAIR') 
    values.push($el.text()) items = values.map(value => parseInt(value)) 
    cy.log('Items', items) 
    expect(items).to.be.within(1,3) -> error expected to be a number or a date

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Thanks for the idea.

```
 if ($el.text() !== REDHAIR') 
    values.push($el.text()) 
    items = values.map(value => parseInt(value)) cy.log('Items', items) 
}).then(() => {
   items.forEach((value) => {
       expect(value).to.be.within(1,3)
   }
}
```

This will iterate the numbers inside an array.